# JQuery Autocomplete Display Error MSG if No Result

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

i found this piece of code somewhere on the net and adapted it to my needs.

hi, may be the rest of my code will help clarify it:

index.php >

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="searchdb.js"></script>

<div>DBLookUp <input id="autocomplete" type="text"  />
<div id="showresults"></div>
</div>
```

searchdb.js >

```
//autocomplete function
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#autocomplete").keyup(function()
            { 
                $("#showresults").show(); 
                var dbsearch; 
                dbsearch = $("#autocomplete").val(); 

                if (dbsearch.length > 0) 
                { 
                    $.ajax( 
                    { 
                        type: "POST", 
                        url: "autocomplete.php", 
                        data: "dbsearch=" + dbsearch, 
                        success: function(message) 
                        { 
                            $("#showresults").empty(); 
                            if (message.length > 0) {
                    $("#showresults").append(message);
                } else {
                    $("#showresults").append("No Results found!");
                }
                        } 
                    }); 
                } 
                else 
                {
                    // if empty
                    $("#showresults").empty(); 
                } 
            });
        });
```

//end of autocomplete function

```
        function selectItem(id,value)
        {               
            document.getElementById("autocomplete").value=value;             
            autocomplete(id,value);
        }
```

autocomplete.php >

```
<?php
require_once("searchdb.php");
$dbsearch = strtolower(mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['dbsearch']))); 
$autocompl=new DBQUERY();
$autocompl->autocomplete($dbsearch);
?>
```

searchdb.php >

```
<?php
class DBQUERY {

private $dbh;

public function __construct() {
    $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb", "root", "");
}

public function autocomplete($dbsearch)
{

  $cons = $this->dbh->prepare("select * from  clients  where  cl_name like :dbsearch");

                    $cons->execute(array(':dbsearch' => '%'.$dbsearch.'%'));
                    while($dbrow = $cons->fetch())
        {
        $data=$dbrow["cl_name"];$id=$dbrow["cli_id"];

                    echo "<a class='resultsdb' href=\"javascript:selectItem
                    (".$id.",'".$data."')\">".$data."</a><br>";
                    }
                  ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".resultsdb").click(function(){
                $("#showresults").hide(); 
            }); 
        });
    </script>
<?php
    }
//end autocomplete
}
?>
```

it works great, but i cant make it show the "no results found!" message.
i think the else-clause is overwritten by the if-statement, which starts to works as soon as it detects input. ( ...if (dbsearch.length > 0)... )

but since im new to jquery i cant seem to figure out where to change the script so that it works correctly.

Comment: The `message` object returned from the `autocomplete.php` file must not be of length <= 0. Try checking the value of `message` when you expect it to be empty to see it's true value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe also this might work:

```
if (message.trim() != "") { 
    //message = message; <-- not needed..
    $("#showresults").append(message); 
}else{
    //message = "No Results found!"; <-- also not needed..
    $("#showresults").html("No Results found!");
}
```

You have to return empty string form your php...
And also, this shouldnt be there...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".resultsdb").click(function(){
                $("#showresults").hide(); 
            }); 
        });
    </script>
```

put this in the document not in php like this:

```
   //autocomplete function
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#showresults").on("click", ".resultsdb", function(){
            $("#showresults").hide(); 
        });

        $("#autocomplete").keyup(function()
        //....
```

Comment: as Bob khin said, return empty string when nothing found, and remove the Script, as it is also an return, and the message is never empty...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check the $cons:

```
public function autocomplete($dbsearch) {
    $cons = $this - > dbh - > prepare("select * from  clients  where  cl_name like :dbsearch");

    $cons - > execute(array(':dbsearch' = > '%' .$dbsearch. '%'));

    if (count($cons) > 0) {
        while ($dbrow = $cons - > fetch()) {
            $data = $dbrow["cl_name"];
            $id = $dbrow["cli_id"];

            echo "<a class='resultsdb' href=\"javascript:selectItem (".$id.",'".$data."')\">".$data."</a><br>";
        } ?>
    } else {
        $data = '';
    }   

    <script type = "text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".resultsdb").click(function() {
                $("#showresults").hide();
            });
    }); </script>
<?php
    }
// end autocomplete
} ?>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your input! unfortunately it doesnt change the result. still dont get error msg :(

Comment: got it working as expected with reyaner's answer, but thx anyway ;)